# Plotting two functions in the same graph with different colors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I would like to plot 2 functions in the same graph in order to visualise the a function and its constraint one, so that I can have a better sense of where the maximum of the function within the range of the constraint function is.

Currently, I am using `ezsurf` to plot a single function at a time.

```
syms x y
ezsurf(5 - x^2 - 1/2*y^2);
```

and my constraint function is

```
ezsurf(x + y - 2);
```

But this only shows the graph of the constraint function (the second one).

Is it possible to visualise both in the same graph, preferably with different colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `hold on` after the first plot  .

hold on retains plots in the current axes so that new plots added to the axes do not delete existing plots. New plots use the next colors and line styles based on the ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder properties of the axes. MATLAB adjusts axes limits, tick marks, and tick labels to display the full range of data.

hold off sets the hold state to off so that new plots added to the axes clear existing plots and reset all axes properties. The next plot added to the axes uses the first color and line style based on the ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder properties of the axes. This is the default behavior.

hold all is the same as hold on. 
 ..... see more [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)

Here's how you control diffrent colors to each surface:

```
colormap([parula(64);gray(64)])

syms x y
h(1)=ezsurf(5 - x^2 - 1/2*y^2);
Z=(get(h(1),'zdata'));
hold on
h(2)=ezsurf(x + y - 2);


m = 64;  % 64-elements is each colormap

cmin = min(Z(:));
cmax = max(Z(:));
% CData for surface1
C1 = min(m,round((m-1)*(Z-cmin)/(cmax-cmin))+1); 
% CData for surface2
C2 = 64+C1;

% Update the CDatas for each object.
set(h(1),'CData',C1);
set(h(2),'CData',C2);

% Change the CLim property of axes so that it spans the 
% CDatas of both objects.
caxis([min(C1(:)) max(C2(:))])
```

[image]

Comment: Could you do it without the Symbolic Toolbox i.e without [syms](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html)

Comment: you can but then you's use `surf` instead of `ezsurf` and have to define the `x,y` grids using `meshgrid` ...